# How can I solve "Uncaught ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined"? Vue.js 2

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

When I run my application, on the console exist error like this :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined

and

> Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined

Whereas, I had run on command line this :

```
npm install
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev pusher-js
```

When I add this :

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'
```

on bootstrap.js, it works

I have two laptop

My first laptop, it without add `import Pusher from 'pusher-js'`, it works

Whether there need to install something?

Why my second laptop need to add `import Pusher from 'pusher-js'`?

Comment: It sounds like you might need to `npm install` on your other computed. There's no way to debug this based on what you've provided though.

Comment: @Bill Criswell, I had run it. But that's very strange because my second laptop has an error

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a thread who have the similar question like you..

Please check the link below:

[pusher not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196598/pusher-is-not-defined-laravel-5-4-with-laravel-echo)

The problem because is due to a change in laravel

and you need to import Pusher from "pusher-js"